# Menu bar notification badge update issue

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, notifications, menubar

I have a menu bar with notification bubble badge (CSS3), and a php script to retrive the new messages count from mysql database (messenger inbox system). I want to update the value of the notification badge every second with the number of unread messages from the script or hide the container  completely if the script result is 0 (no new messages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out after 48 hours awake!

```
setTimeout('pullNewMessageCount()', 200);
function pullNewMessageCount() {
var url = 'models/bubble.php';
$.ajax({
url: url,
dataType: 'html',
type: 'POST',
success: function(latestCount) {
 setTimeout('pullNewMessageCount()', 200);
 $('#bub').html(latestCount);
 if (latestCount > 0)
 {
   $('#bub').removeClass('hidden').addClass('bubble').addClass('animating');
 } else if ((latestCount = $('#bub').html()) && (latestCount > 0)) {
   $('#bub').removeClass('animating');
 } else if ((latestCount = '0') || (!latestCount)) {
   $('#bub').removeClass('bubble').addClass('hidden');
 } else {
   $('#bub').removeClass('bubble').addClass('hidden');
 }
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
}
});
}
```

and finally a working facebook-like notification bubble system!